# How to match a word either after a specific pattern or before another specific pattern?

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have to match a word either after one specific pattern or before another specific pattern.
So, it should match either `<pattern_1> <word>` or `<word> <pattern_2>`. I can do this using the `|`.

```
regex_pattern = r'((?<=pattern_1)word|word(?=pattern_2)'
```

But, is there a better way?

Comment: The wording of your question seems backwards. Based on your regex, you are actually trying to *match a word* either after one specific pattern or before another specific pattern.

Comment: @Booboo Yes, I guess so. I'll make the changes. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @itprorh66 If I'd have resolved the problem, then I'd have answered it and closed it. I'm expecting someone will have some answer.

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data nor any of the code that you have written that produces your problem. Please review Jon Skeet's excellent blog post [WRITING THE PERFECT QUESTION](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) for guidance in updating your question.  For a more detailed tutorial on asking a good question see Eric S. Raymond's site [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Comment: I finally am able to post answers. If you want to give me credit, I can post the solution with explanations.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sure, please do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using

```py
(?<=(pattern_1 ))?word(?(1)|(?=( pattern_2)))
(?<=(pattern_1 ))?word(?(1)| pattern_2)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2A05Df/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=(pattern_1 ))?` - an lookbehind construct that optionally requires a `pattern 1` substring (*captured into Group 1*) immediately to the left of the current location
- `word` - a string
- `(?(1)|(?=( pattern_2)))` - a conditional construct that does the following:

  - `?(1)` - if Group 1 was matched, do nothing
  - `|` - else
  - `(?=( pattern_2))` - a positive lookahead that matches and captures  `pattern_2` string immediately to the right of the current location. It seems you might also just use  `pattern_2` instead of the lookahead pattern (but it won't get captured then).